# Frameworks: Zend Framework 1.11 vs Symfony vs Zend Framework 2 (Comparison and Advantages/Disadvantages)

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1

**How to choose between the following frameworks? When to chose Zend when Symfony, or other?**

Of course you have seen this kind of topic often around the internet already. This time I want to start a **constructive** discussion in order to know which framework should be chosen over another. I want to learn one of them as soon as possible, because CodeIgniter seems to have it's limitations.

Some criteria reduced my choice to the popular Zend Framework and Symfony, because of there massive documentation. I need to practice, and teach it to other employees.

I would like to know, based on your **experiences** and **research** what are the advantages and disadvantages of both Frameworks.

You will ask: What are your needs. Well, none and all together. Make small to big sites, by having one workaround. It’s certain that different people will work on those different projects. Besides that, the programmers can be experienced and junior in **OOP**.

Please do not answer with the sentence that it is a question of taste and style. I don’t have any yet.

Criteria:

- Documentation
- High Load sites
- Modules
- Copy features to other projects easily.
- OOP
- PHP > 5 (5.3 pre)
- Templates
- Caching
- Backend with complex a Database.

*I really want to learn a new Framework. Help me choose!*

**Zend Framwork 1.11**

- Lot of documentation
- Lot of tutorials
- Zend Certification (good for your CV)
- End of development cycle.

**Zend Framework 2**

- PHP 5.3
- The future ?
- Beta

**Symfony**

- PHP 5.3
- Good Documentation
- Bundles (Website regrouping them)
- Usability (Development bar at the bottom of the screen)
- Speed
- Twig implemented (bridge)
- Doctrine implemented (bridge)
- Good reputation
- Less known
- Smaller community

Comment: Put in *why* you choose this two,and what are the criteria you want to know for a constructive answer, and the question *might* become less subjective (being both well-established products, with their ins and outs, it's difficult to provide *objective* standpoints. There will be many aspects where one is better than the other, and the contrary.)

Comment: Please read the [faq], this type of question doesn't fit our question/answer format. [ask]

Comment: *"I want to start a constructive discussion"*. From the FAQ: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's see if this makes it in before the thread gets closed.

1. ZF2 - Beta release in Oct 2011, nothing since then, no real point in even considering it.
2. ZF1 - Nice and stable, bit dated but it works.  Lots of useful integrated components such as PDF.
3. Symfony 2 - Your question is chock full of misunderstandings.

Lots of tutorials - Nope.  You might be thinking about SF1.4.  The only thing 1.4 shares with 2.0 is the name.  S2 tutorials are still a work in progress.

Easily implement zend libraries - Not sure what this means but yes you can use some ZF 1 components such as pdf quite easily.

Bundles - good thing but nothing new.  Everyone has some sort of module support.

Twig is not implemented natively.  What is known as a bridge allows you to use twig inside of s2 with minimal effort.

Doctrine 2 is also not implemented natively. Also uses a bridge.  Which is good because other database packages such as Propel can plug right in as well.

The big thing you missed completely about S2 is that it is built around dependency injection and services.  I know ZF2 is supposed to have something similar but S2 is out there and available today.

You also overlooked CodeIgniter and CakePhp.

Comment: Well. 3 down votes and -6 rep.  Guess that teaches me not to post on these sort of threads.